# access denied - PHP move_uploaded_file - Ubuntu LAMP /var/www

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, permissions

I realize there is some sort of problem with permissions on either my *tmp* folder or the *images* folder I created in the /var/www folder. I know that /var/www initially has root access. I have been following some online tutorials to try and fix this issue and have changed my permissions to who knows what over the last hour or so.

I receive this error when trying to upload a file from an HTML form using PHP/MySQL:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/verified-gw.gif): failed to open stream: Permission  
denied in /var/www/addscore.php on line 40 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 
'/tmp/phpla4QCP' to 'images/verified-gw.gif' in /var/www/addscore.php on line 40 cannot 
move uploaded file or something beavis
```

So I think the permissions on either the /var/www/images folder are incorrect or the permissions on the *tmp* folder are root and the kernel of ubuntu is not letting the php script move from this root owned file to the *images* folder which has permissions of my user account to my knowledge and is in the group nobody.

I am pretty lost, any help is definitely appreciated.

[image: Ubuntu Linux gnome screenshot of permissions of a folder]

Above you can see a picture of the permissions on the images folder I am trying to move the file from the tmp directory to.

Oh and here is the PHP script that fails:

```
if (!empty($screenshot)) { 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name'], $target) 
or die (' cannot move uploaded file or something beavis');
```

Respectfully,

user

Comment: Try `sudo chmod 755 -R /var/www` This will give all your files and directories inside /var/www with enough read write permissions.

Comment: @Rao I still receive same error... :/ but thank-you for trying to help. :D

Comment: This should be `chmod 777 -R /var/www/project/uploads` directory.

Comment: I do not have an uploads or project directory in www though :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This solved my problem: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1842090&s=8b97ec72fe7cd753910f488329a90f0f&p=11239688#post11239688

tl:dr - I typed this: `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`

I do not think it was a combination of trying to chmod the chown the tmp directory and this. I think it is just changing the permissions on the /var/www folder where all LAMP files are kept.

Now the PHP script works and tosses the image file in the directory I made. It would be easier if Ubuntu installed test servers like this LAMP stack in the user directory without having to learn file permissions like I am protecting my files from the nazis' submarines.

Answer (score 15):

### working with USER DIR mod

If this is developer machine, and i think it is, dont try to use /var/www (there will be always permission problem)
Try to use [user dir](http://www.techytalk.info/enable-userdir-apache-module-ubuntu-debian-based-linux-distributions/)

you will keep all your files and projects in your home and there will be no permission problems.

### working with Apache root dir

Ok, so if you cant work with user dir, you have to set up file system like this:

**1.** Find out apache owner user name. If you use Ubuntu, it should be www-data. Go to terminal and type:

`$ ps aux | grep apache`

You should get something like this below. First column is username.

`www-data  2070  0.0  0.0 463244  7788 ?        S    sty25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start`

**2.** Find out apache user group. Again terminal, type:

`$  sudo groups www-data`

You should get something like this below. Second column is group name.

`www-data : www-data`

**3.** Set RIGHT owner user and owner group for apache root dir:

`$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/`

**4.** Set RIGHT privileges for apache root dir:

`$ sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/`

Now you have your system cleaned up, and we try to fix your user to have access to /var/www directory.

**5.** Add apache group to your user:

`$ sudo usermod -a -G www-data {YOUR_USER_NAME}`

**WARNING!** dont forget -a switch! this way you append new group to existing list and not replace old groups list with new one.

Now you have read/write access to files located in apache root dir. And we need to tell apache that new files should be readable/writable to group members

**6.** Add umask command to apache enviroment config:

`$ sudo echo umask 002 >> /etc/apache2/envvars`

or with graphic editor:

`$ gksudo gedit /etc/apache2/envvars`

and place `umask 002` as last line in this file

**7.** Voila

`$ sudo apache2ctl restart`

Good luck!

Comment: I tried this but it did not work for me. :/ I am not sure why nothing is working today. This method seems kinda scary from an info security perspective too. Thanks for this idea though, I had no idea about user dir before your post. :D

Comment: I just realized that this probably does not work for me because I have my home folder encrypted... I get 403 FORBIDDEN errors when trying access either static .html files or dynamic PHP scripts. :/

Comment: Ok, so if you cant work with user dir, you have to clean up apache privileges and add r/w access for your user to apache root dir. I have edited post, try this out.

Comment: wow you know a ton about Ubuntu Linux and Apache2. Thank-you for the help. I already answered my own question, but thank-you for explaining more of the details about why the solution I found works. I am definitely going to have to learn more about permissions and apache2.

Comment: @WebHQ, thanks for the nice and details answer! I added the missing usermod to step5 :)

Comment: @insidepower thanks :) Thanks, that you noticed missed command. I see that is still missing, so i try to add it by my self.

Answer (score -3):

try this: `sudo chown -R 777 /var/www/images`

you need to give the file a public permission 777 OR 755 so the file can be uploaded to the specified directory its only a permission