# php move_uploaded_file returns true but file is missing on localhost

Tags: php

I am trying to move one image to new folder **move_uploaded_file** is returning 1 but the file is missing, I am working on localhost with XAMPP

```
$name = basename($_FILES['arr']['name'][0]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arr']['tmp_name'][0],"\Images");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - using move\_uploaded\_file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510156/php-using-move-uploaded-file)

Comment: I would use single quotes around \Images instead of double quotes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should specify the destination file name

```
if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arr']['tmp_name'],dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/' . $_FILES['arr']['name'] ) ) {
    echo "file uploaded";
} else {
   echo "error in uploading";
}
```

Comment: When i tried it gave me this   Warning: move_uploaded_file(/Images/22730356_1664914676962402_7473132350479803631_n.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload.php on line 19

Comment: you need to specify the full path!

Comment: @BorislavShopov I have updated the answer and you should have `images` folder, since `move_uploaded_file` cannot create folder itself

Comment: Awesome , Happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = basename($_FILES['arr']['name'][0]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arr']['tmp_name'][0],'/images/' . $filename);
```

You have to add a destination for the file to go, including the filename that you wish to assign to it.

Refer to: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: [`"\n"`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) means new line. I doubt a file name that contains it is useful and usable.

Comment: Well if you read the PHP documentation it states, ' If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by destination.'. Within the code he has written there is only a directory path and not a filename.

Comment: What @axiac means is that inside double quotes, a `\n` will be interpreted as a newline, so your filename is probably borked. Maybe you meant `"\\Images\\newname"`...? No idea.

Comment: @JosephHarris is correct ! he missed the filename, and his and my answer are correct. There is no point to downvote.

Comment: Actually, axiac is right. You should use single quotes instead of double quotes to prevent \n being translated to a new line.

Comment: On Linux and macOS, the forward slash (`/`) is the directory separator but it is perfectly safe to use it on Windows too. PHP handles both `/` and `\ ` as directory separators on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, so its okay to use forward slash instead of confusing both.